# Calculating AIC/BIC for individual contrasts within a LMM model

Tags: r, model

I have been asked by reviewers to provide AIC/BIC values to support a claim of a null effect. 
However, my model is a 2 x 4 model in which each condition is compared to a baseline condition.

The design is like this:

```
age (2 levels) young, old

Length (4 levels) baseline, length 1, length 2 and length 3
```

In the LMM model, each of these lengths differs from the baseline. There is also an interaction between age and the comparison of baseline versus length 1, but no interactions with age for any of the other comparisons.

Our conclusions are based on the lack of interaction between age and these other lengths.
I have been asked to calculate AIC/BIC values to support this. However, I can only get the AIC/BIC for the whole model (not individual comparisons), and, as the LMM model does have 1 interaction, this isn't helpful what I am trying to demonstrate.

Is it possible to compute a AIC/BIC to specifically demonstrate e.g. there is no interaction between Age and baseline vs length 3?
I can only do this by excluding the other conditions, but then the model is no longer the same model used for the LMM analyses.
Is this a logical thing to do?

I have extracted the values using the anova function and the AIC function

e.g.

```
anova( lmm1, lmm2)
```

Where `lmm1` is a model with a main effect of age and length and `lmm2` is a model with main effects plus an interaction.

I have also tried excluding conditions when doing the calculation.

Comment: @ "However, I can only get the AIC/BIC for the whole model (not individual comparisons)": TO my understanding you estimate AIC/BIC for the whole model, then for another model where you leave out some predictors (features). The difference in AIC/BIC shows you the importance of the effects that are missing in one of the models

Comment: You could improve the readability if you format the `code`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I understand that, and I have tried comparing the model with age + length to the model age * length. But I am not sure if I can specify a model containing interactions only between specific levels of a factor, without simply removing the levels from the analyses i.e can I demonstrate specifically that there is no interaction between age and baseline vs length 1? I'm sorry if I am not very clear.